# SQLite: Get all entries in an specific timespan

Tags: sqlite

I want to get all entries in a specific timespan. I have a column named "Date" which simply stores a date like "2024-05-01". For example I want to get all entries in the from 2023-01-01 to 2023-05-10 from the Table "Touurs".

I'm searching and trying for hours but didnt find a solution.

I already tried things with strftime but didnt work

Comment: That sounds trivial. What did you try? Shouldn't need `strftime()` or any other functions...

Comment: it's just `select ... where date between "2023-01-01" and "2023-05-10" ... ;` if strings are guaranteed to be formatted properly

Answer (score -2):

To search dates I have created the SQLite DB like this
NOTE I only use txYear and txSearchMonth these value are not entered by extracted from date today when I enter data in the Check Book Program
Dim create_table As String = String.Empty
create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TxData(
TID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
txSortDate TEXT,
txYear INTEGER,
txType TEXT,
txAmount TEXT,
txCKNum TEXT,
txDesc TEXT,
txBalance TEXT,
txSearchMonth INTEGER)"

Here is the search routines I use drop down combobox to select search info
The variables with the preface gv are global variables defined in a DataModule read about Module it is only available in VB.Net NOT C#

```
    Private Sub ViewSearches()

    Dim intID As Integer
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strTxType As String
    Dim strAmt As Decimal
    Dim strCKNum As String
    Dim strDesc As String
    Dim strBal As Decimal
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim maxRowCount As Integer
    Dim emptyStr As String = "  "

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("", conn)

            If gvSearchType = "All" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData"
            ElseIf gvSearchType = "MoRangeYr" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth >= $gvFromMonth AND txSearchMonth <= $gvToMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth BETWEEN $gvFromMonth AND $gvToMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvToMonth", gvToMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
            ElseIf gvSearchType = "MoYr" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth = $gvFromMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
            ElseIf gvSearchType = "TxMoYr" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txType = $gvTxType AND txSearchMonth = $gvFromMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvTxType", gvTxType)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)

            ElseIf gvSearchType = "Year" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txYear = $gvYear"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
            End If
```